# If any dropdown value changed from a group of dropdowns which is equal to other dropdown selected value, then entire other dropdown should be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Hi, I'm new to Javascript and/or Jquery, I'm practising them the scenario of question is
>   "Using button, dynamically add dropdowns with values not selected in previous dropdowns, after that if any value of random dropdown option from the existing dropdowns is changed and if that changed(or selected) value is equal to other dropdowns already selected value, then the entire other drop down should be removed from the code."

I'm having trouble in, if I change any value in between which is equal to other dropdown value, then the entire other drop down should be removed from the code, but that drop down is not getting removed.

Kindly help.
Thank you.

HTML Code---

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
    <select class="dropdown" name="ddlFruits1" id="ddlFruits1">
    <option value="m">Mango</option>
    <option value="a">Apple</option>
    <option value="b">Banana</option>
    <option value="o">Orange</option>
    <option value="e">Me</option>
    <option value="y">You</option>
    </select></p>
</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery Code---

```
  $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var index = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    var ddl=  $('<select class="dropdown" name="ddlFruits" id="ddlFruits">\
    <option value="m">Mango</option>\
    <option value="a">Apple</option>\
    <option value="b">Banana</option>\
    <option value="o">Orange</option>\
    <option value="e">Me</option>\
    <option value="y">You</option>\
        </select>');

    ddl.attr("id", "ddlFruits" + index);
        ddl.attr("name", "ddlFruits" + index);

    for(i=1;i<index;i++){
            var selectedValue = $("#ddlFruits"+ i+" option:selected").val();
        ddl.find("option[value = '" + selectedValue + "']").remove();
        }
/* var selectedValue = $("#ddlFruits"+ index+" option:selected").val();
 for(i=1;i<index;i++){
 var d=$("#ddlFruits"+i).clone();
 alert(i+d+selectedValue);
 d.find("option[value = '" + selectedValue + "']").remove();
 $("#ddlFruits"+i).replaceWith($(d));
 }*/

 if ($('#ddlFruits'+(index-1)+ ' option').length == 1) {
    $('#ddlFruits'+index).hide();
    alert("all values finished");
    return false;
}
        index++;

        ($('<p>').appendTo(scntDiv)).append(ddl).append($('<a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p'));
    });

    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        dropdownval = $(this).val();
        $('.dropdown').not(this).find('option[value="' + dropdownval +                      '"]').remove();
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( index > 2 ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
      index--;
        }
        return false;
        });
});
```

CSS Code---

```
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

[Partial Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/16707/)

[Parital Working Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/dsee1455/)

Please check Demo2 and suggest, Thank you.

Comment: You should include a fully working, minimal example here, and then explain what the problem with that example is. Also note that you're using outdated methods, like `live()` and `size()`

Comment: sorry to ask, but is the fiddle code not working(I checked now, its working for me) and about outdated live(), size(), can you please suggest what to use which I will use later, but as of now I would like to solve the functionality problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: I have added the code here along with the link, thanks for the suggestion post, I didn't know the problem and not fully even now, but from next time  I will add code in SO

Comment: I'll try to help you out, and post an answer, but it uses a modern version of jQuery, and somewhat simpler code

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to keep track of the selected values, and insert a new select without any previously selected values

```js
$('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
 var clone    = $('#ddlFruits1').clone(true);   // create a clone of the first select
    var values   = clone.find('option').length;    // number of available values
    var p        = $('<p />');                     // create a new paragraph
    var dp       = $('.dropdown');                 // get all selects on the page
    var selected = dp.map(function() {             // map the selected value of the selects
     return this.value;
    }).get();
    
    clone.attr('id', dp.length + 1)                // increment the ID of the clone
         .attr('name', dp.length + 1)              // and the name
         .find('option').filter(function(_,option) {  // then filter the options based on wether or not
          return selected.indexOf( option.value ) !== -1; //  their value has already been selected
         }).remove(); // and remove any from the clone that have prevoiusly been selected
    
    if (dp.length < values) // if there are values left to select ..
     p.append(clone).appendTo('#p_scents'); // add the new select to the paragraph, then to the parent
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

h2 a {
    color: #224f99;
}

a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #802727;
}

p {
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

input {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -web-kit-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <select class="dropdown" name="ddlFruits1" id="ddlFruits1">
            <option value="m">Mango</option>
            <option value="a">Apple</option>
            <option value="b">Banana</option>
            <option value="o">Orange</option>
            <option value="e">Me</option>
            <option value="y">You</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean code, 
I'm adding remove button to remove a dropdown, not working

In Javascript---
 
var remove = $('<a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>'); 

Instead of    
p.append(clone).appendTo('#p_scents');  
adding   
p.append(clone).append(remove).appendTo('#p_scents'); 

And adding remove function as     

   $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
     $(this).parents('p').remove();
     return false;
  });

But code is not working,can I know reason.    
Other problem is,if any drpdn changed value is equal to other drpdn,other drpdn should be deleted

Comment: Thank you very much Adeneo for the addon code, I dont know why my above code not even going to remove fun. I tried to vote you, but since I'm new to SO, its not showing. Now could you suggest me regarding my main problem, so that I can go in right way to solve.
Problem is, suppose I have 6 dropdowns with different selected values, now I will change one of them to a value which is already selected in other dropdown, now action should be that the entire other drop down along with <p>i.e. <p>dropdown</p> should be removed.
Is the country-state depended dropdown going to work for this. Thank you